# How to iterate json string which holds array of object in controller

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

**I have converted array of object into json string in jsp as follows**

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){

        var sample = new Array();

           var k = 1;
            for(var i=0; i < JSONObj.length; i++){ 

               var remarkString = $("#eduRemark"+k).val();
               var scoreNum = $("#eduScore"+k).val();

               var objectInfo = {"iqrQuestionRemark":remarkString, "iqrQuestionScore":scoreNum,"crtnByUmId":""};
               sample.push(objectInfo);

                k++;
            } 

        var ArrayData = JSON.stringify(sample);
         alert("Json Data:"+ArrayData); 

            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                  dataType : 'json',
                  url: "/Vidyasaarathi/ipusers/submitAssessmentform",
                  data: ArrayData, 
                  success :function(result) {

                            }
                });


        });
```

**The ajax call works fine. At controller side i'm getting list of object as String. in following format**

```
[{"iqrQuestionRemark":"nitin","iqrQuestionScore":"10","crtnByUmId":""},{"iqrQuestionRemark":"akash","iqrQuestionScore":"12","crtnByUmId":""},{"iqrQuestionRemark":"sharad","iqrQuestionScore":"14","crtnByUmId":""}]
```

**Now my question is how to iterate this array of object individually at controller side.**

**Here is my controller code**

```
@RequestMapping(value={VspCommonConstants.INTERVIEW_PANEL_MANAGER_URL+"/submitAssessmentform"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitAssessmentform(@RequestBody List<InterviewQuestionResult> ArrayData,HttpServletRequest request,Model model) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //String [] actualData = mapper.readValue(ArrayData, String[].class);
        //System.out.println("Json converted Data:"+actualData);
        System.out.println("Result object:"+ArrayData);
        String view = null;

        try {
            view = "ipsearchForm";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            model.addAttribute("errormsg", "System is busy...... Please try after some time.");

        }
        return view;
    }
```

**Please suggest some possible way. Here i'm trying to assign json string to 'InterviewQuestionResult'  bean which has a getter setter. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: could do you paste as well your InterviewQuestionResult bean? technically you shouldnt need to do anything special, if the bean is mapping your attributes and json structure properly the bean should fill up by spring automatically

Comment: use .forEach check some examples here
https://www.baeldung.com/foreach-java